# Cannot read property formatMessage of undefined error message from react code

Tags: reactjs

I have a function below and trying to do translation to another language
for days of the week. Here is my function below. 
All I get is "TypeError: Cannot read property 'formatMessage' of undefined"
The name of my js file which contains the function below is daso

```
    const daysOfTheWeek = props => ([
      {
        text: props.intl.formatMessage({
          id:'Monday',
        }),   
      },
      {
        text: props.intl.formatMessage({
          id:'Tuesday',
        }),    
      },
      {
        text: props.intl.formatMessage({
          id:'Wednesday',
        }),    
      },
    ].map((day, dayId) => ({
      ...day,
      dayId
    })));
```

The function above will be used like this

```
    <Select
          value={props.selectedDay}
          onChange={event => {
            event.preventDefault();
            props.onChangeDay(event.target.value);
          }}
        >
          {
            daso(props).map((day, index) => (
              <MenuItem
                key={index}
                value={day.dayId}
              >
                {day.display}
              </MenuItem>
            ))
          }
        </Select>
```

Any ideas of what am doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you defining `intl`? Is that something you get through async code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to export your function. In `daso.js`:

```
export {
 daysOfTheWeek,
 //etc.
}
```

and then in your `imports` of your Component:

```
import { daysOfTheWeek } from 'daso.js'
```

then instead of calling `daso(props)`, call `daysOfTheWeek(props)`